# Why doesn't StackApps have a chat link?

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, stackapps

Is it because [the only room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=stackapps.com) for the site is frozen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The room being frozen is simply because it has been inactive. I'll re-open it. As for why stackapps doesn't have the link... good question. I'll investigate.

---

The flag has been set; this should appear in the next day.

Comment: I know why rooms get frozen :)

Comment: @radp - updated

Answer (score 1):

Chat has been enabled for StackApps and will be live after our deploy tonight.